# Сортировка по различным полям C++

Tags: c++, сортировка

Есть такой класс:

```
class Abiturient
{
  private:
    string fullName;
    string birthDate;
    string score;
    string schoolName;
    string course;
};
```

Нужно реализовать сортировку по различным полям, поле выбирает пользователь.
Мой код:

```
void Abiturient::sort(vector<Abiturient> &arr, int selection, bool descending)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < arr.size(); n++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            switch (selection)
            {
            case 1:
                if (trimSpace(stringToLower(arr[i].fullName)) > trimSpace(stringToLower(arr[i + 1].fullName)))
                {
                    swapElements(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
            ...
```

Топорно, конечно, прошу строго не судить, только учусь. Как можно сделать сортировку лучше? И желательно через функцию sort библиотеки algorithm. Пытался с помощью лямбды сделать подобие анонимной функции так:

```
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [=selection](Abiturient first, Abiturient second) {
        switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            return first.fullName < second.fullName;
        case 2:
            return first.birthDate < second.birthDate;
        ...
        }

    });
```

Но не выходит, не совсем понимаю, как захватывать значение

Comment: Что  такое "но не выходит"? Потрудитесь привести осмысленное описание проблемы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не пытайтесь запихнуть все в одну лямбду. Будет только запутывать.

Напишите несколько дружественных (для доступа к полям) функций сравнения по полям - типа,

```
bool lessByName(const Abiturient& a, const Abiturient& b)
{
    return a.fullName < b.fullName;
}

bool lessByScore(const Abiturient& a, const Abiturient& b)
{
    return a.score < b.score;
}
```

А там и сортируйте, как надо

```
switch (selection) {
    case 1:
        sort(array.begin(),array.end(),lessByName);
        break;
    case 2:
        sort(array.begin(),array.end(),lessByScore);
        break;
```

или как там вам нужно...