# Сортировка массива структур C++

Tags: c++, сортировка, структуры

Есть массив строк:

```
char towns[][str] = { "Юрюпирийс 4000   Москва",
                "Москва    500    Питер ",
                "Мурманск  900    Луга  ",
                "Питер     2300   Москва"};
```

Я разделяю его в массив структур:

```
Airport_Pass s1[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    strncpy(s1[i].Departur, towns[i], DepartureLen);
    s1[i].Departur[DepartureLen] = '\0';

    char dop[80];
    strncpy(dop, towns[i] + DepartureLen, DistanceLen);
    s1[i].Distance = atoi(dop);

    strncpy(s1[i].Destination, towns[i] + DestinationStart, DestinationLen);
    s1[i].Destination[DestinationLen] = '\0';

    cout << " [" << s1[i].Departur << "] " << s1[i].Distance << " [" << s1[i].Destination << "]" <<endl;
}
```

Нужно **спросить** у пользователя **по какому полю сортировать массив структур и вывести отсортированные структуры**.Не могу понять как именно сделать сортировку по определённому полю.Нужно использовать одну функцию,а вот как это сделать - не знаю.По одному полю могу отсортировать,а по вбранному полю - нет

---

Полный код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int DepartureLen = 9;
const int DistanceLen = 7;
const int DestinationLen = 9;
const int DistanceStart = DepartureLen;
const int DestinationStart = DistanceLen + DistanceStart;
const int str = DestinationStart + DistanceStart + 1;
struct Airport_Pass {
    int Distance;
    char Departur[DepartureLen + 1];
    char Destination[DestinationLen + 1];
};
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    Airport_Pass s1[4];
    char towns[][str] = { "Юрюпирийс 4000   Москва",
                          "Москва    500    Питер ",
                          "Мурманск  900    Луга  ",
                          "Питер     2300   Москва"
    };


for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    strncpy(s1[i].Departur, towns[i], DepartureLen);
    s1[i].Departur[DepartureLen] = '\0';

    char dop[80];
    strncpy(dop, towns[i] + DepartureLen, DistanceLen);
    s1[i].Distance = atoi(dop);

    strncpy(s1[i].Destination, towns[i] + DestinationStart, DestinationLen);
    s1[i].Destination[DestinationLen] = '\0';

    cout << " [" << s1[i].Departur << "] " << s1[i].Distance << " [" << s1[i].Destination << "]" <<endl;
}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966086/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc-c - практически ваш вопрос...

Comment: @Harry ,там используются вектора,которые я не знаю,а также встроенные алгоритмы сортировки.Как можно написать функцию,которая будет принимать массив и поле,по которому сортировать?Хотя бы начало ,чтобы я дальше сам попробовал додумать

Comment: После использования `strncpy` для `Departur` вы догадались добавить в результат замыкающий `\0`, а после использования `strncpy` для `dop` - вдруг напрочь об этом забыли. Это как так получилось? Вам пока везло из-за того, что там в конце стоят пробелы. А если вдруг пробела не будет?

Comment: @AnT , так оно же всё равно преобразуется в число потом.Ну а так спасибо,я добавил

Comment: В смысле "все равно"? Функции `atoi` на вход нужна **строка**. Строка должна заканчиваться символом `\0`. Вопросы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int DepartureLen = 9;
const int DistanceLen = 7;
const int DestinationLen = 9;
const int DistanceStart = DepartureLen;
const int DestinationStart = DistanceLen + DistanceStart;
const int str = DestinationStart + DistanceStart + 1;

const int LEN = 4;

struct Airport_Pass {
    int Distance;
    wchar_t Departur[DepartureLen + 1];
    wchar_t Destination[DestinationLen + 1];
};
int main() {
    //setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    Airport_Pass s1[LEN];
    wchar_t towns[LEN][100] = { 
        L"Urupirsp 4000   Moskva",
        L"Moskow   500    Piter ",
        L"Murmansk 900    Luga  ",
        L"Piter    2300   Moskva"
    };


    auto departureCmp = [](const Airport_Pass & a, const Airport_Pass & b){return wcsncmp(a.Departur, b.Departur, DepartureLen) < 0;};
    auto destCmp = [](const Airport_Pass & a, const Airport_Pass & b){return wcsncmp(a.Destination, b.Destination, DestinationLen) < 0;};
    auto distCmp = [](const Airport_Pass & a, const Airport_Pass & b){return a.Distance < b.Distance;};

    std::map<int, bool (*)(const Airport_Pass &, const Airport_Pass &)> mp {
        {1, departureCmp},
        {2, destCmp},
        {3, distCmp},
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        wcsncpy(s1[i].Departur, towns[i], DepartureLen);
        s1[i].Departur[DepartureLen] = '\0';

        wchar_t dop[80];
        wcsncpy(dop, towns[i] + DepartureLen, DistanceLen);
        s1[i].Distance = wcstol(dop, nullptr, 10);

        wcsncpy(s1[i].Destination, towns[i] + DestinationStart, DestinationLen);
        s1[i].Destination[DestinationLen] = '\0';

        wcout << L" [" << s1[i].Departur << L"] " << s1[i].Distance << L" [" << s1[i].Destination << L"]" <<endl;
    }

    wcout << L"\nChoose field:\n1 - Departure\n2 - Destination\n3 - Distance";
    int variant;
    cin >> variant; // Добавить проверку введенного варианта
    std::sort(s1, s1 + LEN, mp[variant]);
    wcout << L"\nSorted:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        wcout << L" [" << s1[i].Departur << L"] " << s1[i].Distance << L" [" << s1[i].Destination << L"]" <<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Здесь строки заменены на длинные.

Comment: Спасибо,всё работает)Ожидал что-то проще,но сейчас буду разбираться